# Is there a utility software to set a default sound output level for a number of MP3 tracks?

Tags: audio, mp3, sound

Some of the tracks in my MP3 collection have low output sound and this requires that I adjust volume level back and forth every time such a track plays and completes. Is there an application that I can use to set a common output level for all my MP3 files?

I mostly use Winamp and sometimes Realplayer to play my music.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This Winamp blog post](http://blog.winamp.com/2009/08/24/automatic-volume-leveling-in-winamp-with-replay-gain/) describes exactly what you are looking for. The function is called `Replay Gain` and can be applied as follows (relevant text cited from blog article in case the link goes down):

> 1. Select the files you would like adjusted (DO NOT try to calculate
>      your entire library at once)
> 2. Right click and choose Send To -> Calculate Replay Gain
> 3. Once the files are analyzed, choose "Save As Album".
>
>    - only choose "Save Track data" if you just have one (or a few) tracks from a particular album.
> 4. Once you've scanned your library, you'll still need to set your
>      Preferences to turn on Replay Gain. Put a check-mark next to the
>      Preferences to turn it on. (Ctrl+P) Playback -> Replay Gain tab ->
>      Select "use Replay Gain".
>      Under "Preferred source", you can freely
>      toggle between the album & track playback options w/o rescanning. The
>      only time you'll need to rescan is when you add new songs to your
>      library.
>
>    - Select "Track" if you are going to listen to your library on shuffle or if listening to a playlist
>    - Select "Album" if you are going to listen to complete albums

Comment: Yes, this was exactly what I was looking for. I didn't know it was called 'Replay Gain'. Thanks a lot for the detailed walk-through. Unfortunately, I can't voteup your answer. The system won't let me as I don't yet have minimum required reputation.

Answer (score 3):

Windows Media Player (version 12, not sure of other versions) have an option that might help you.

In the "Options" window, in the "Library" tab there's a checkbox near the top that you can use to configure to **Add volume leveling information values for new files**.

I believe (but I'm not sure) this information is then stored to the file as an ID3 tag.

Other programs should have a similar option and functionality.

Comment: I haven't got WMP12, but I will see if the feature you have mentioned is available on Winamp and RealPlayer.